# changing url segment htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to replace

```
http://url.com/section1/category2/title
```

with

```
http://url.com/title
```

in a wordpress htaccess file.

I cant do this in the permalinks area of WP bc we have a bunch of custom permalinking rules, so everything I do needs to be done in the htaccess file.

Comment: Are you after a simple redirect? (I don't think so by the sounds of it.)  "I cant do this in the permalinks area of WP" - If you are wanting to change the URL (ie. effectively change the permalink structure) then, unfortunately, that is the only place you can change it - within WordPress.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us the relevant bits from your current htaccess.

Comment: I'm SURE this is possible via htaccess. I think I have the htaccess code wrong. We have all kinds of Match redirects for broken links, but the swap stuff I'm not so good at. I see other people doing this, but i'm missing some part of it.